# How to convert multiple objects into 1 JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json

My application has a list of reports and each 'Report' is defined as a new object in PHP. I'm trying to make a basic API and I want to show a list of all the 'Reports' in 1 JSON string. My code below works well for encoding 1 object into JSON, but how do I get ALL objects and turn ALL of them into 1 long JSON string?

I understand I could make an array of objects, but that returns these brackets [] and I don't want those brackets in the JSON string.

```
class report {
    public $report_name;
    public $report_value;
    public $report_benchmark;
    public $report_result;

    public function __construct($report_name, $report_value, $report_benchmark, $report_result) {
        $this->report_name = $report_name;
        $this->report_value = $report_value;
        $this->report_benchmark = $report_benchmark;
        $this->report_result = $report_result;
    }
}

$item = new report('test', 0, 0, 'OK');
echo json_encode($item, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: add a number of objects to an array and `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: This comment could have been the answer to this question. Great @JimL. :)

Comment: I did consider that, but if I do that I then get `[ {"test": "test"} ]` and I don't want the [ ] brackets.

Comment: @user5331188 You said you want a json string, and *that* is a perfectly  valid json string.

Comment: You don't want the brackets ? But the brackets are necessary for the JSON output to be actually valid. Maybe you want the array itself encapsulated into an outer object ? Like this: `{"result": [ ... ] }` ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise it couldn't be valid JSON without it and I will look into encapsulating it into an outer object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @JimL, you can simply add some objects in an array, which you can encode as json latter on.

```
$item = array();
$item[] = new report('test', 0, 0, 'OK');
$item[] = new report('test2', 0, 0, 'OK');
echo json_encode($item, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

produces:

```
[{
    "report_name": "test",
    "report_value": 0,
    "report_benchmark": 0,
    "report_result": "OK"
}, {
    "report_name": "test",
    "report_value": 0,
    "report_benchmark": 0,
    "report_result": "OK"
}]
```

Note here that you can validate the produced json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: But if I do that I then get `[ {"test": "test"} ]` and I don't want the [ ] brackets.

Comment: @user5331188 in the above example, it won't be a valid json in case the brackets are missing

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this.

```
$item = array();
$item['report1'] = $item = new report('test', 0, 0, 'OK');
$item['report2'] = $item = new report2('test', 0, 0, 'OK');
$item['report3'] = $item = new report3('test', 0, 0, 'OK');
echo json_encode($item, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

make an associative array and add assign all objects a meaning full key, which will help to easy access each specific report.